# How to remove private members and keep comments in auto generated typescript definition files

Tags: typescript

I have two questions about the typesript compiler.

I use the autogenerating definition feature of the typescript compiler. The result includes private symbols:

```
export declare class WorkerController {
    static LIBRARY_ROOT_PATH: string;
    private _worker;
    private _entryPoint;
    private _externalScripts;
    constructor(entryPoint: string, externalScript?: Array<string>);
    spawn(): void;
    private _test();
}
```

Is it possible to not include these?

I would also like to include the documentation comments that I have on my code. Is there a special keyword to preserve those?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to stop emitting declarations for the private variables and functions.

Assuming that you have a **tsconfig.json** or a similar way to configure **tsc** you can set the **removeComments** option to **false**.

If set to false documentation comments will be left in the source. A documentation comment must start with /** instead of /* or //.

You can find more info on configuring tsc [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json).